# Install graph-tool for Anaconda Python3.6.3 on macOS X

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

How can I install graph-tool for Anaconda Python 3.6.3 on macOS High Sierra? (I've been able to install graph-tool for Python 2.7.10.) Thanks!

I followed the instructions and first tried

```
brew tap homebrew/science
```

but got "Error: homebrew/science was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated." Anyhow, I found a solution (forgot the exact brew command) and ran

```
brew install graph-tool
```

It now says "Warning: brewsci/science/graph-tool 2.26_1 is already installed". I can then import graph-tool from python 2.7,

```
$ /usr/bin/python2.7
>>> from graph_tool.all import *
```

but not from the anaconda distribution,

```
$ python
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct  6 2017, 12:04:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from graph_tool.all import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graph_tool'
```

Comment: Have you read the [installation instructions](https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/wikis/installation-instructions#macos-x)? How did you install it for 2.7, how did you try to install it for 3.6, and what was the error or problem?

Comment: I also tried to build myself with the configure script, but then I got the message "configure: error: pycairo headers not found"